# Angular 2 When I submit the form the data is coming empty

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm really new to Angular 2, I just finished studied Angular 1x and then I knew that it has increased its version.

My problem is I'm not getting the data on the component.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center"> Cadastro Teste </h1>
<form (submit)="cadastro($event)" >

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Nome : </label>  
              <input type="text" (ngModel)="pessoa.Nome" name="Nome" class="form-control"/> 
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label> Email : </label>  
              <input type="text" (ngModel)="pessoa.Email" name="Email"  class="form-control"/> 
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </div> 
  </div>

</form>    
</div>
```

Component :

```
import {Component}  from '@angular/core';


@Component({
   moduleId : module.id,
   selector : 'teste',
   templateUrl : './teste.component.html'

})
export class TesteComponent{


  pessoa;

  cadastro(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      console.log(this.pessoa);

  }
}
```

I'm using TypeScript

Comment: What does **not getting the data on the component** mean exactly? Are you having some default values you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your template:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="cadastro($event, form)" >
</form>
```

In your component change your function to this:

```
cadastro(event:Event, form: NgForm): void {
  console.log('form data', form.value);
...
}
```

And add the import for NgForm in the top:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular 2 is different from Angular 1 you need to change a bit from `(ngModel)` to `[(ngModel)]`

`ngModule` directive belongs to `FormsModule` then you have to import `FormsModule` to your app

Your `tests.module.ts`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule  // <--- import here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Your `teste.component.ts` change `pessoa` to object `pessoa = {};` for access `Nome` and `Email` in html template

```
export class TesteComponent{
  pessoa = {};

  cadastro(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.pessoa);
  }
}
```

and finally, your html template change a bit to this

```
[(ngModel)]="pessoa.Nome" 

[(ngModel)]="pessoa.Email"
```

That's it. I hope this helpful to you.